# Little-o of a summation

Tags: summation, asymptotics, euler-mascheroni-constant

I'm having trouble proving that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1} = \log(n)/2 + \log(2) + γ/2 + o(1)$$
as $n → ∞$.

I honestly don't even know where to start, and I don't know what the $o(1)$ is supposed to signify. Can someone please help me?

Comment: $o(1)$ is a sequence (say $\varepsilon_n$) converging to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Start with $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\log n+\gamma+\varepsilon_n.$$
Then $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\log(2n)+\gamma+\varepsilon_{2n}-\frac12\left(\log n+\gamma+\varepsilon_n\right)\!\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Your expression looks like

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1} = \log(n)/2 + \log(2) + γ/2 + f(n)$$

with

$$f\in o(1) \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big|\frac{f(n)}{1}\Big|=0$$

This is obviously equivalent to

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(n)=0$$

which means, that anything that is left after the summand $\frac{\gamma}{2}$, will vanish when considering the limit for $n\rightarrow\infty$